# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{5^k \sqrt k}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $a_k=(-1)^k \frac{1}{5^k \sqrt k}$.

This is an example in my book, the author claims that according to the root test the limit does not exist, because $a_k=0$ for k odd (is this true?), but proceeds to show that it indeed has a convergence radius of $R=5$, with the argument that limsup for a bounded sequence always exists.

Comment: $\frac1  R=\lim \sup |a_k|^{1/k}$.

Comment: I think it should be $a_k=(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{5^k\sqrt{k}}$

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness. The power series also converges on the boundary, i.e $|x|=\sqrt{5}$ due to the Alternating series test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_k$ is definitely not zero for $k$ odd, unless $x=0$. With the $x^{2k}$ inside:
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{1/k}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{x^{2k/k}}{(5^k)^{1/k}k^{1/2k}}=\frac{x^2}5$$
Thus the series converges when $x^2<5$, i.e. the radius of convergence is $\sqrt5$.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $t=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5}}$ then the inifinite sum is polylog of t.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{∞}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{5^k \sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{∞}(-1)^k\frac{t^k}{\sqrt{k}}=PolyLog(\frac{1}{2},-t)=PolyLog(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5}})$$

Have a look at [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). This is granted by the law, that is a new series can be led back to a well known series, it converges like that one modified by the substitution necessary to transform both series into each other.

This is a Dirichlet power series in $s=-\frac{1}{2}$. This definition is valid for arbitrary complex order $s$ and for all complex arguments $z$ with $|z| < 1$. In this question $x$ with $|x| < \sqrt{5}$. **It can be extended to $|x| ≥ \sqrt{5}$ by the process of analytic continuation.** This follows by the definition of the power series of $PolyLog$.

Central to the prove by using the $k$-root limes superior law is that
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow∞}k^{\frac{1}{2k}}=1$$

That is not easily seen ad hoc. $k^{\frac{1}{2k}}=\exp (\frac{1}{2 k} \log k)$. We can now take the limit of the argument of $\exp$ since this function is well behaved. We know already that $k$ grows much fast than $\log$ for large value. So the exponent approches $0$ for very large $k$. Some limit that exists properly exist as a quotient to. The limes superior $k$-root law helps and proves the result.

On the real axis

[image: plot of the series on the real axis for x>-1 without the substitution]

[image: plot of the series on the real axis for x>-1 with the substitution]

The result by comparison to the known series provides a rather different convergence behavior than the rules and laws. We get ride of the singularity at $-1$ because the argument is square an the factor is positive. The singularity would be at $1$ if the sign was not explicitly changed.

The radius of convergence of the series on the real axis for $x$ is ℝ. The example shows that substitution and search a suitable well known power series is much mightier than using the laws.

Comment: Wow ! Ithink that your answer will be very, very ,very helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Show that

$$|\frac{a_{k+1}x^{2k+2}}{a_kx^{2k}}|= \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}} \cdot x^2.$$

Hence

$$|\frac{a_{k+1}x^{2k+2}}{a_kx^{2k}}| \to \frac{x^2}{5}$$

as $k \to \infty$.

From

$$\frac{x^2}{5} <1 \iff |x| < \sqrt{5}$$

we get thst the radius of convergence is $R= \sqrt{5}$.